# Can I run Tensoflow Serving on Raspberry Pi locally?

Tags: raspbian

I am building a speech recognition application to be run on Raspberry Pi 3. I have developed a Tensorflow model for this purpose that I am able to run on Raspberry Pi through command line.

How do I make a call to this model from my application (both on Raspberry Pi)? Should I install and run Tensoflow Serving on Raspberry Pi to serve the model (I tried this and got an Exec format error on running tensorflow_model_server)?

I want both the model and my speech recognition application to run locally on Raspberry Pi to avoid any network delay.

Comment: Do you have tensorflow installed on your RPi? Which version of Raspbian are you running it on?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use it for low-cost computational problems.

However, for large datasets it can take a long time to process.
Use this for install and configure: [Deep Learning on Pi: Install TensorFlow on Raspberry Pi 3](https://www.deciphertechnic.com/install-tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/)